# Server cannot read json values from Android : Undifined IINdex and json null received at Server

Tags: php, android, json

I am going to implement the client-to-Server module which request is sent from Android devices to php . When it comes to the implementation , I have no clue why the server side cannot receive the json sent from Android device . As for the server, the database insert module is OK but cannot catch the json values . Would you please tell me what is wrong with the client side ?

The below is my code

Client side Android

```
public String postData(String argument , String url) {

        String result="";
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

        int timeoutConnection = 60000 * 20;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);

        int timeoutSocket = 60000 * 20;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParameters, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(httpParameters, 8*1024);


        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);


        //Log.d("url" , url);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);



        try {   
            System.out.println("Response:"+ "start execute");

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("userid","loka");
            json.put("password","yoor");
            json.put("email","johnsmith@example.com");   


            //Log.d("test" , jsonString);
            httppost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
            httppost.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
            //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            //If php json response required
            if(status==200){

                HttpEntity getResponseEntity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream httpResponseStream = getResponseEntity.getContent();
                 result = slurp(httpResponseStream , 8192);
                System.out.println("result: "+  result);

            }else{

                System.out.println("2");
                result = String.valueOf(status);
                HttpEntity getResponseEntity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream httpResponseStream = getResponseEntity.getContent();
                 result = slurp(httpResponseStream , 8192);

            }



        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();            
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();            
            return e.getMessage();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;  
    }
```

Server side php

```
<?php


header('Content-type: application/json');
ini_set('display_errors','On'); 

require_once 'lib_mysql/insert.php';
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

 $result =insertUser($json);

 if($result) {
 echo "success";
 }
 else{

echo "fail"; 


}


?>




include_once("connection.php");

function insertUser($jsonString){

 $usern = $jsonString->userid; //Undefined Variables
 $pass = $jsonString->password; //Undefined Variables
 $email = $jsonString->email; //Undefined Variables

$conn = getDBConn();

$data = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `json_decode()` function in php. `header('Content-type: application/json');` would not help in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try this way hope this helps you

Relpace

```
httppost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
```

with

```
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8));
```